# VueJS how to register global before guards

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

beforeEach hook for every route like [in the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards):
My page should scroll to the top on route change.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   window.scrollTo(0, 0)
      next();
})
```

but my router has another structure and its not working:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Contact from '@/components/Contact'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({

  beforeEach: (to, from, next) => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    next();
  },

  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/kontakt',
      name: 'Contact',
      component: Contact
    },
  ]
})
```

Thanks in advance =)
Or is it better to use the .created hook on the components to scroll to the top of the page?

```js
  created() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adapt your code to the structure required in [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Contact from '@/components/Contact'

Vue.use(Router)

// create object router with the valid initialization
const router = new Router({    
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    component: HelloWorld
  }, {
    path: '/kontakt',
    name: 'Contact',
    component: Contact
  }, ]
});

// add the beforeEach hook
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  next();
});

// export router as default
export default router;
```

Comment: beforeEach() doesn't trigger when using the export default new Router() syntax, don't know why

Comment: @MariusAndreiana have you tried following the syntax in my answer? That's the way described in the docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! Just noted that the other way, ```export default new Router() ```, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put Router.beforeEach after creating router.